# VS Code just renders Javascript file as Text using Live Server Extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio

I just started to learn and practice ReactJS. however, when I first set up ReactJS along with the npm and node.js it worked fine. But today, whenever I want to access the index.js (a sample code from my-app for React) it just outputs the text in my browser. I have tried reinstalling both VS Code and Live Server Extension and still doesn't work.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your project file, you just need to run:

> npm i

> npm start

Comment: I'm sorry for a noobish question but what is the exact syntax for that and where should I add that code?

Comment: In the VS menu > Terminal > New Terminal or press ctrl + shift + ò
Then in the terminal run:
npm i   > to install dependencies if you have or if you cloned the project. If not, just run directly:
npm start
and it will open localhost:3000

Comment: Thank you so much! This has helped me gain ideas on what to do/search for and it is working now.